# How do I determine type of Dictionary comparer in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, stringcomparer

I need to determine whether a Dictionary I receive in a function has a case-insensitive comparer.

ie. A case insensitive dictionary is declared like so:

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<string, decimal>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

When I receive the dictionary into my function I can access the .Comparer property and check its type - however all I seem to get is -

```
System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer<string>
```

How can I find out if the Comparer being used is StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your scenario; passing that comparer in and checking the `.Comparer` gets a `System.OrdinalComparer`. Are you sure you aren't using the default constructor, i.e. `new Dictionary<string, decimal>()` ?

Comment: hmm - I've stepped through the code and I'm fairly certain I'm not using the default constructor. The other thing is that the behaviour of the function changes with respect to the case-sensitivity - so the StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase is having an effect when I add it to the constructor.

Comment: Sorry - you're right. I was getting mixed up between some test code and the real stuff. The answer below does the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the value, not the type against StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.

```
myDict.Comparer == StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase
```